# Cannot hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I intend is:

When phone button is clicked, phone no. appears and email, if shown, disappears.

When email button is clicked, phone no., if shown, disappears and email is shown.

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/adzk6tnv/.

When I do not hide the email id initially, it works fine. When I click on phone button, the email id disappears and phone no. appears, but the same does not happen when **both** are hidden initially.

Please can someone help me out?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".no").hide();
    $(".email").hide();

    if($(".email").is(":visible")){
        $(".phone").click(function(){
        $(".email").slideToggle(function(){
            $(".no").fadeIn();
        })})
    }
    else {
        $(".phone").click(function(){
            $(".no").slideToggle();
        })
    }

    if($(".email").is(":visible")){
        $(".mail").click(function(){
        $(".no").slideToggle(function(){
            $(".email").slideToggle();
        })})
    }
    else {
        $(".mail").click(function(){
            $(".email").slideToggle();
        })
    }       
})

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p class="text-muted">Designation</p>
    <p class="text-muted no">+91 8888888888</p>
    <p class="text-muted email">something@gmail.com</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="phone" href="#">phone</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="mail"href="#">email</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neither of them are visible because you hide them both. You add click handlers to them, but how can you "click" on something that isn't visible?

Comment: You add different click handlers depending on the visibility on document ready, you should use one click handler and inside you should check the visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simplified version.

It slides up the unwanted data.  (If not visible, it does nothing.)

When complete, it toggles the wanted data:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.no, .email').hide();

  $('.phone').click(function() {
    $('.email').slideUp(function() {
      $('.no').slideToggle();
    });
  });

  $('.mail').click(function() {
    $('.no').slideUp(function() {
      $('.email').slideToggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <h4>Name</h4>

  <p class="text-muted">Designation</p>

  <p class="text-muted no">+91 8888888888</p>
  <p class="text-muted email">something@gmail.com</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="phone" href="#">phone</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="mail" href="#">email</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are only binding the click handler for `.phone` if `.email` is visible:

```
if($(".email").is(":visible")){

    $(".phone").click(function(){
    $(".email").slideToggle(function(){
        $(".no").fadeIn();

    })})
}
```

Since `.email` starts out hidden, you never bind the handler so clicking it does nothing.

Comment: i have also used an else statement, so if .email is not visible that code should run and the phone no. should appear

Comment: Not really, the code in the else statement only binds a click handler that would run when you click on `.phone`. It doesn't actually show `.phone` until you clicked it. This answer by @RickHancock is much better http://stackoverflow.com/a/31710901/3146

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as Rich Hitchcock's answer, I've produced the results you wanted.  The slideUp timing is not as succinct and defined but it does showcase more control with timing as well as your original intent of setting the conditional `is(':visible')` statement.

**jQuery**

```
//Show Hide onClick functionality - Alexander Dixon 2015
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710666/promblem-in-hide-and-show
//http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/
var $phoneEmail = $('li > a'),
    $emailLink = $('li a.mail'),
    $phoneLink = $('li a.phone'),
    $viewPhone = $('p.no'),
    $viewEmail = $('p.email');

//Initially hide the phone and email fields function declaration
function hideBoth() {
    $viewPhone.hide();
    $viewEmail.hide();
}

//Run the function to hide the fields
hideBoth();

//Prevent the link from behaving like a link
$phoneEmail.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

//Bind a mouse down (very similar to a click) event to the email link that will slide show email view in 300 milliseconds
$emailLink.on('mousedown', function() {
    if($viewPhone.is(':visible')) {
        $viewPhone.slideUp(205);
    }
    $viewEmail.slideToggle();
});

//Bind a mouse down (very similar to a click) event to the phone link that will slide show phone view in 300 milliseconds
$phoneLink.on('mousedown', function() {
    if($viewEmail.is(':visible')) {
        $viewEmail.slideUp(205);
    }
    $viewPhone.slideToggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p class="text-muted">Designation</p>
    <p class="text-muted no">+91 8888888888</p>
    <p class="text-muted email">something@gmail.com</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="phone" href="#">Phone</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="mail"href="#">Email</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```